# Login problem with Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux, login, gnome-boxes

I was running Kali Linux in gnome boxes just like virtualbox and I was running out of space so I used gnome boxes to increase the hd capacity. Now when attempt to login the screen goes blank for a fraction of a second and asks for the user name and password again and will not log me in.

I don't think that it is because of boxes, it's because I changed the hd size and Kali crapped out.

I can alt shift f1 and log in.
How could I fix? It? Please thx

Answer (score 0):

You've increased the capacity of the virtual disk, but you haven't edited the partition table and extended the filesystem within the partition, so the filesystem cannot use the increased capacity yet. How to fix it depends on exactly how the virtual disk is set up: MBR or GPT partitioning? One or many partitions? Is LVM in use?

An X11 GUI login will typically fail just like that if the filesystem that contains your home directory is 100% full. Login using Ctrl-Alt-F1 and run `df -h` to see if any of your filesystems is at 100%. If you can, free up a little bit of disk space, then you will be able to login using the GUI again.